# Infinite repeating of highscore in processing

Tags: java

I'm writing a `highScore` in a game. The goal of the code is to get a score and after filling in your name, the score is added, then saved in an excel file. Somehow, it keeps repeating and repeating an infinite amout of times.

How can i fix this?

```
import java.util.*;

// A single score
class Score {
  // has the name of the player
  String name;
  // and his/her score
  int score;

  // Constructor
  Score(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
  }
}

// ScoreList class manages a list of scores
class ScoreList {
  ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
  Table scoreTable;

  // Constructor
  ScoreList() {
    scoreTable = new Table();
    scoreTable.addColumn("name");
    scoreTable.addColumn("Time");
  }

  // Create a new Score and add it to the scores ArrayList
  void addScore(String name, int score) {
    // Add a new score object to the scores ArrayList
    scores.add(new Score(name, score));
    // Sort the scores ArrayList after each score is added
    sortScores();
  }

  // return amount of scores in scores ArrayList 
  int getScoreCount(){
    return scores.size();
  }

  // return the score at iScore
  Score getScore(int iScore){
    return scores.get(iScore);
  }

  // Sort the scores ArrayList
  void sortScores() {  
    Collections.sort(scores, new HSComperator());
  }

  // Save scores to file named "scoreFileName"
  void save(String scoreFileName) {
    // Copy scores from ArrayList to table
    for (Score score : scores) {
      TableRow row = scoreTable.addRow();
      row.setString("name", score.name);
      row.setInt("Time", score.score);
    }

    // save the table to file
    saveTable(scoreTable, scoreFileName);
  }


  // Load scores from file called "scoreFileName"
  void load(String scoreFileName) {

    // Load the scores into the Table object
    scoreTable = loadTable(scoreFileName, "header");

    // clear scores ArrayList
    scores.clear();

    // copy scores from table to the scores array
    for (int iScore=0; iScore<scoreTable.getRowCount(); iScore++) {
      TableRow row = scoreTable.getRow(iScore);
      scores.add(new Score(row.getString("name"), row.getInt("Time")));
    }
  }
  void draw() {
  background(0);
  theUserInput.draw();
  // display header row
  textSize(20);
  text("Place        Name        Time", 100, 70);

  textSize(16);
  // for each score in list
  for (int iScore=0; iScore<theHighScore.getScoreCount(); iScore++) {

    // only show the top 10 scores
    if (iScore>=9) break;

    // fetch a score from the list
    Score score = theHighScore.getScore(iScore);

    // display score in window
    text((iScore+1) + "            " + score.name + "        " + score.score, 100, 100 + iScore*20);


  }
}
}

// Comperator class is needed in order for processing to know how
// to sort a list of scores
class HSComperator implements Comparator<Score> {
  @Override
    public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
    return o1.score - o2.score;
  }
}

void keyTyped() {
  if (theBuilder.curLevel == 4) {
    theUserInput.typing = theUserInput.typing + key;    
    if (pressedKeys[5] == true) {
      theHighScore.load("highScore.csv");
    }
    if (key == '\n') { 
      theUserInput.saved = theUserInput.typing;
      theUserInput.typing = "";
      theHighScore.addScore(theUserInput.saved, theTimer.Seconds);
      theHighScore.save("highScore.csv");

    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Where is your `saveTable(scoreTable, scoreFileName)` function?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Where exactly it goes into infinite loop?

Comment: Between void save and void load

Comment: When i loaded the score

Comment: Crap, forgot to add some code, im so sorry

Comment: paste content of saveTable?

Comment: @frederickvandermeulen I can see where it is called, I meant where is the actual function?

Comment: @DanielStanley Im sorry, im not that experienced with coding and stuff, I dont understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: @almasshaikh What do you mean with youre question?

Comment: You are calling saveTable(scoreTable, scoreFileName); where is it in your code above in question?

Comment: Again, im sorry, but if you meant where as in where it is staying, it is in the void save method. after the loop, saveTable saves teh code

Comment: @frederickvandermeulen You say that `saveTable` saves the code? OK so how does it do that? to call `saveTable(scoreTable, scoreFileName);` you must have a function somewhere like: `public void saveTable(Table scoreTable, String scoreFileName) { //lots of lovely functional code here }` that's what we want to see!

Comment: @DanielStanley Thank you for your explanation!(yay), after checking the code, i came to the shocking thingy that i didn't had one! What would you recommend to fill in the method? Thank you for spending time with my problem!

Comment: @frederickvandermeulen I haven't done that before so can't offer code but check out tutorials like: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html good luck!